# On variations of a claim due to Kaneko in terms of Lehmer means

Tags: number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory, means, divisor-sum

In this post (now cross posted as this [question on MathOverflow with identificator **362866**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362866/on-variations-of-a-claim-due-to-kaneko-in-terms-of-lehmer-means)), for a tuple of positive real numbers $\mathbb{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ we denote its corresponding Lehmer mean as $L_q(\mathbb{x})$, where $q>0$. This is an important example of mean, the Wikipedia article dedicated to this mean is [*Lehmer mean*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_mean) that includes a section for *Applications*. As aside comment I don't know if any definition of mean enjoys of the feature explained in this section of applications with relation to signal processing.

Also we denote the sum of divisors function as $$\sigma(n)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$$ for integers $n\geq 1$.

The idea of the post was to combine this definition of Lehmer mean with an equivalent formulation of the Riemann hypothesis, I refer the last paragraph of [1] (Kaneko's claim for a suitable choice of the integer $n$).

From here, my belief that there should be an integer $n_0>1$ such that $\forall n\geq n_0$ the following inequality holds $$\sigma(n)<\exp\left(\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}\right)\log\left(\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}\right)\tag{1}$$
with $q>0$ (**(!)** this is false for $0<q<1$, see the answer).

**Fact (Is false for** $0<q<1$, **see the answer below).** *We've from the theory of Lehmer mean that we recover the inequality of Kaneko as* $q$ *(or* $|q|$*) tends to* $0^{+}$.

> **Question.** I would like to know what work can be done to get an inequality $(1)$ for a very small $|q|$ (I mean very close to $0$) that holds $\forall n\geq n_0$ for your suitable choice of $n_0>1$ (and your $q$, what I want is $|\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\frac{1}{k}-n/L_q(1,\ldots,n)|$ small). **Many thanks.**

I emphasize that I'm asking **what work can be done** to prove an example for one of those inequalities $(1)$ for a very small quantity $q>0$. Optionally feel free to add your feedback about if this type of inequalities and combinations can be potentially interesting.

**Final remarks:** 1) My interpretation was for the $RHS$ of the mentioned inequality (from the article of Lagarias) due to Kaneko. I don't interpret (if it is interesting) in a similar way the $LHS$ that is the sum of divisors function (I don't know if it is feasible*). 2) If I understand well the veracity of some equivalences to the Riemann hypothesis, that were stated as inequalities involving certain arithmetic functions, depends (counterexamples) on certain integer sequences. And I don't know if it is feasible to create a mean that enjoys the same feature than the Lehmer mean (the mentioned in first paragraph, see also the link *power mean* from the cited Wikipedia's article for *Generalized mean*).

### References:

[1] Jeffrey C. Lagarias, *An Elementary Problem Equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis*, The American Mathematical Monthly, 109, No. 6 (2002), pp. 534-543.

[2] P. S. Bullen, *Handbook of Means and Their Inequalities*, Springer, (1987).

Comment: * In the literature are expressions for the sum of divisors function (but now I don't know how get an interesting interpretation using a suitable definition of a mean), for instance from page 141 of G. H. Hardy, *Ramanujan: twelve lectures on subjects suggested by his life and work*, AMS Chelsea Publishing (2002); or from  George Purdy, *An Integral Equal to* $\sigma(n)$, Problems and Solutions, Problem E 1850 [1966, 82], The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 74 N. 5, p. 594-595 (May, 1967).

Comment: Many thanks for the attention of all users and for the upvoter.

Comment: I've decided accept an answer, since as was emphasized I'm asking what work can be done . Many thanks for the attention and answer of the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

This answer proves the following two claims :

**Claim 1** : It is false that if $q$ is a fixed number satisfying $0\lt q\lt 1$, then there is an integer $n_0>1$ such that $(1)$ holds $\forall n\geq n_0$.

**Claim 2** : If $q$ is a fixed number satisfying $-1\lt q\lt 0$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}=\infty$$

---

**Claim 1** : It is false that if $q$ is a fixed number satisfying $0\lt q\lt 1$, then there is an integer $n_0>1$ such that $(1)$ holds $\forall n\geq n_0$.

*Proof* :

For $0\lt q\lt 1$, we get 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^q\gt \int_{0}^{n}x^qdx=\frac{n^{q+1}}{q+1}$$
and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{q-1}\lt 1+\int_{1}^{n}x^{q-1}dx=\frac{n^q-1+q}{q}$$

It follows from these that

$$\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}=\frac{n\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{q-1}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^q}\lt\frac{n\cdot\frac{n^q-1+q}{q}}{\frac{n^{q+1}}{q+1}}=\frac{(n^q-1+q)(q+1)}{n^{q}q}$$

Let $f(x)=\frac{(x^q-1+q)(q+1)}{x^{q}q}$. Then, we have $f'(x)= \frac{1-q^2}{ x^{q+1}}\gt 0$. So, $f(x)$ is increasing with
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{q+1}{q}\bigg(1+\frac{q-1}{x^q}\bigg)=\frac{q+1}{q}$$
from which we have
$$\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}\lt f(n)\lt\frac{q+1}{q}$$
So, we get
$$\small\exp\left(\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}\right)\log\left(\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}\right)\lt \exp\left(\frac{q+1}{q}\right)\log\left(\frac{q+1}{q}\right)=(\text{a constant})$$

Considering $\sigma(2^m)=2^{m+1}-1$, we see that the conjecture is false. $\quad\square$

---

**Claim 2** : If $q$ is a fixed number satisfying $-1\lt q\lt 0$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}=\infty$$

*Proof* :

For $-1\lt q\lt 0$, we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^q\lt 1+\int_{1}^{n}x^qdx=\frac{n^{q+1}+q}{q+1}$$
and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{q-1}\gt \int_{1}^{n+1}x^{q-1}dx=\frac{(n+1)^q-1}{q}$$

It follows from these that
$$\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}=\frac{n\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{q-1}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^q}\gt\frac{n\frac{(n+1)^q-1}{q}}{\frac{n^{q+1}+q}{q+1}}=\frac{n((n+1)^q-1)(q+1)}{qn^{q+1}+q^2}$$

Finally, we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n((n+1)^q-1)(q+1)}{qn^{q+1}+q^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q+1}{q}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{(1+\frac 1n)^{-q}}-n^{-q}}{1+\frac q{n^{q+1}}}=\infty$$

Comment: Many thanks I'm going to study your result. I've added an inequality as combination of Kaneko's inequality and a definition for means. Thus 
a priori if I'm right the statement/conjecture should be true for some values of $q$ (in other case there was a fatal error in my combination). Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user759001: To be clear, my answer proves that it is false that if $q$ is any fixed number satisfying $0\lt q\lt 1$, then there is an integer $n_0>1$ such that $(1)$ holds $\forall n\geq n_0$.

Comment: Many thanks now I'm confussed ,that I think that you've proved in that my **Fact** (version that $q>0$ for $0<q<1$) is false. Your statement is right, but if my combination if right for some $q$ let say $|q|$ then the question can be interpreted for these negative values of $q$. Thus if I didn't a fatal error in my combination (the fourth paragraph) the motivation and **Fact** are (partially) wrong but the **Question** is unanswered.

Comment: @user759001: Ah, I didin't notice that you are writing $|q|$ instead of $q$ in the Question. Later, I'll try to examine the case where $-1\lt q\lt 0$.

Comment: Many thanks any case you notice that my **Fact** is false for $q>0$ thus your answer is helpful. Many thanks for your patience and generosity of sharing your excellent answers here.

Comment: @user759001: I've just added a proof of another claim, but the claim is all I can get for now.

Comment: Many thanks I' ve decided award the bounty. I hope that there was no more mistakes in my post. I understand that then an inequality of the form $(1)$ make sense for small values of $-1<q\leq 0$. In this case your second claim is according with the divergence of $\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\frac{1}{k}$.